# Integrating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(ax)}\cdot \sin(\sin(ax))}{x^2+1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to compute the family of integrals:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(ax)}\cdot \cos(\sin(ax))}{x^2+1} dx$$

and

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(ax)}\cdot \sin(\sin(ax))}{x^2+1} dx$$

for positive real $a$

I started by defining

$$ C(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{cos(ax)} \cdot \cos(\sin(ax))}{x^2+1}dx$$

and

$$ S(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(ax)} \cdot \sin(\sin(ax))}{x^2+1}dx$$

Then

$$ C(a) + iS(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{(e^{\cos(ax)}) \cdot (e^{i\sin(ax)})}{x^2+1}dx$$

$$ = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{e^{iax}}}{x^2+1} dx$$

$$ C(a) + iS(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{iax})^n}{n!} dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\cos(nax) + i\sin(nax))}{n!} dx $$

This implies that

$$ C(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nax)}{n!} dx$$

Swapping the summation and integral signs, we get

$$ C(a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nax)}{x^2+1} dx $$

The integral inside has a really nice closed form:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1} = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot e^{-a}$$

From that, we obtain a satisfying result for $C(a)$:

$$ C(a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{-na}}{n!} = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot e^{e^{-a}}$$

But I could not evaluate a closed form for $S(a)$, which is given by:

$$S(a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nax)}{x^2+1} dx$$

This integral inside the sum should converge, by Dirichlet's test for convergence. We can also establish the absolute convergence of the integral with certainty since the absolute value of $\sin(x)$ never exceeds 1.

Can someone provide any methods to evaluate this integral's closed form? Also, I doubt whether even obtaining a closed form for the inner integral will be enough - after all, we also have to take the sum of the expression multiplied by $\frac{1}{n!}$ over all $n>0$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: The integral $S(a)$ may not have a closed form. In fact, the integral inside the last sum can be calculated via quarter-circle contour. The result is $\displaystyle{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin (nax)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{na}\mathrm{Ei}(-na) + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-na}\mathrm{Ei}(na)}$.

Comment: @HuanyuShi  Thanks for the comment. Can you verify the closed form result I have obtained for $C(a)$?

Comment: For any function that has a Maclaurin series with real coefficients and a radius of convergence greater than $1$, $$\Re\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(e^{iax})}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{2} f(e^{-a}).$$ $C(a)$ is the case $f(z) = e^{z}$.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thanks, this is a really nice observation! I wonder what this identity would be if the term in the denominator is something of the form $x^{2n}+1$.

Comment: For $n=2$, I get $$\Re\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(e^{iax})}{1+x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}} \left(\Re \left(f(e^{-a/\sqrt{2}+ia/\sqrt{2}})\right)+\Im \left(f(e^{-a/\sqrt{2}+ia/\sqrt{2}}) \right)\right). $$  See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NIntegrate%5Be%5E%28cos%283x%29%29*cos%28sin%283x%29%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2Cinfinity%7D%5D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi%2F%282*sqrt%282%29%29*%28Re%28exp%28e%5E%28-3%2Fsqrt%282%29%2Bi*3%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%29%29%2BIm%28exp%28e%5E%28-3%2Fsqrt%282%29%2Bi3%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%29%29%29).

Comment: @RandomVariable Seems to correlate when I substitute $f(z) = z$. I had asked about that case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831424/computing-integrals-of-the-form-int-0-infty-frac-cosaxxb1dx-usi). Seems to agree for $b=4$.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus The calculation result of C(a) is correct. If the deminator of the integrand is $x^{2n}+1$, you can construct $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos nax }{1+x^{2n}}\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\cos nax}{ 1+x^{2n}}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Re}\oint_{C} \frac{e^{inaz}}{1+z^{2n}}\, \mathrm{d}z,$$ where C is the semicircular contour. S(a) cannot be calculated in this way because it does not have such symmetry. This is also why I think S(a) has no closed form.